# pkpass won't open on iOS from e-mail attachment

Tags: ios, email, passbook

All websites mention that Passbook passes can be sent by e-mail. But when the pass (generated by our server) is attached to an e-mail, the iOS e-mail client won't open it and write "(null)" instead. The same pass works fine on Android and also has no problems communicating with our web service. Any ideas? Google searches didn't offer any solutions.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Alex, was this question for ios6 or ios7? I'm having a similar issue, but I've not been able to solve it yet.

Comment: For both but we only tried it on iOS 7. iOS seem to be very strict with field validation. For example it wouldn't work if the value of one of the fields was null. Did the 'solved' post below help you?

Comment: Alex, I went through and recreated all of the certificates and completely overhauled my approach using Simon Waldherr's approach (https://github.com/SimonWaldherr/passkit.php). I do have it working now on iOS 7. Thanks for starting this post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved: There were multiple problems:

- The authentication token has to be at least 16 characters long
- I used the "Apple Inc. Root Certificate" (wrong one) instead of the "AppleWWDRCA" (correct one)
- For production the web service needs to use https

Comment: Hi Alex, could you please elaborate on the "authentication token" issue? How did you set it? I seem to have the same problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21705439/safari-ios-cannot-open-passbook-pkpass

Comment: The value for the field "authenticationToken" in pass.json has to be at least 16 characters long. So just put something like this in your json: "authenticationToken":"1234567890abcdef"

Comment: You can omit the `"webServiceURL"` and `"authenticationToken"` fields. They're optional and only relevant for "pass updating" I believe.

Comment: We use them because we need pass updating.

Answer (score 2):

You get that when the pass in invalid, most likely due to it being incorrectly signed and/or the pass certificate has expired.

Drag your pass into iPhone Simulator and check the Console app to look for error in the logs.

Comment: I'm developing on Windows and don't have access to the simulator. The certificate was generated today.

Comment: Still sounds like a signing error. Are you including the WWDR certificate and a signing date? If you can attach a link to your .pkpass bundle we can take a look.

Comment: We use the upper WWDR certificate from here: http://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/
And here is the pkpass file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/n8p1z764o1zdjdv/pass.pkpass

Comment: this should be the real answer.